# What size should a threaded coupler/fitting be if angle valve inlet is sized 1/2"(2cm)?

Tags: plumbing, valve, fitting

I plan to get these parts:

[image: Angle Valve]
[image: Coupler]

Just unsure if the coupler is the correct size for the angle valve inlet. The shop does also sell one that is 3/4(2.5cm).

For more context, the angle valve that leads up to the bathroom faucet is leaking when I open the valve. No leaks when it's closed. I'm planning to replace it and I asked around and apparently the current angle valve I have is 3/8" x 1/2". It has a female inlet(?) that looks to be 1/2 (2cm) and male outlet(?) that looks to be 3/8 (1.5cm).

[image: bad angle valve]
[image: connected hose line]

Comment: When converting units, start with 1" = 25.4mm. So your 2cm is not 1/2"...

Comment: @popham I edited my post for more details. And ok I understand not using pvc on metal. Those images with measurements are their product listings already. The angle valve they list as 1/2 x 3/8, hence my title as 1/2. I can get a metal coupler from a different shop, it's the size that I'm unsure on. Apologies if I'm asking in the wrong place, I'm no pro on this and just diy-ing it.

Comment: @SolarMike That's what I also assume and know the conversion to be. But seems like plumbing/pipe sizes with outer/inner diamaters, nominal sizes are just different? I edited my post to include the angle valve that needs replacing.

Comment: Those look like tapered threads on the valve's outlet, but I can't be sure. What does the end of the hose that you disconnected look like? And your valve's 1/2" indicates an iron pipe size of 1/2", where the 1/2" is the _inside_ diameter. Your valve's inlet is 3/8" FIP (Female Iron Pipe).

Comment: Here's an example of your valve: https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-3-8-in-FIP-Inlet-x-3-8-in-Comp-Outlet-1-4-Turn-Angle-Ball-Valve-KTR15X-C1/205214457, assuming that you've got a compression connection at the outlet as is typical. I would like to see the disconnected line's end to confirm.

Comment: @popham I'm obviously missing something here, but if the iron pipe size is 1/2", how can the valve's inlet be 3/8"? Isn't 3/8" smaller than 1/2"? Regarding the hose end, really sorry but hope this suffices for now: https://imgur.com/jUAJX9Y. I haven't actually disconnected the one in use, the one in the image is for the other side.

Comment: The inlet's iron pipe size is 3/8". See my answer. That hose is a compression fitting like I anticipated, so that's 3/8" compression. The linked valve a couple comments back meets the spec without any adapters.

Comment: Pipes are sized by the **hole in them**. Pipe threads are therefore **always** larger than the nominal size, as the nominal size is the size of the hole.

Comment: Did you just unscrew something from that "angle valve" picture? If so, take that thing to the store and find out what will screw onto it. Then you'll know for certain. Once you know the size, you can look for the connecting piece you need with that size/shape thread. Every big-box store employee in America expects you to do this - I've had numerous employees help me hunt through the bins of parts looking for something that's a likely fit. It's not really all that hard. Trying to measure and guess? That's hard.

Comment: @FreeMan That old angle valve doesn't have anything attached to begin with. I didn't want to remove it yet as that would require turning of water main, I don't have a cap and family needs water. If the parts I get turns out to be wrong then I'll just take this old valve instead to local hardware store.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a similar valve nearby that you could close, remove the pipe, then see if it fits this one? If so, you could take _that_ hose to the store to see what threads it is. Otherwise, take your rule with you, find a fitting that matches the diameter, and buy a variety of different thread types that match. Return the ones that don't fit. Most places will not only happily accept the returns but will expect you to do something like this.

Comment: @FreeMan, it's clearly a compression fitting judging by the braided stainless in the final image. After some trivial math you can look it up by cross checking a few commercial sources (the official source, SAE J514, is behind a paywall). Or you can check Figure 19B and column B from Table 7 at https://archive.org/details/fluidconductorsc0000unse/page/58/mode/2up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current valve is 3/8" FIP x 3/8" compression. Whoever told you 1/2" was wrong. The 1/2" valve inlet from your proposed valve requires an unnecessary adapter that should be avoided if possible. Be sure to use pipe dope instead of PTFE tape, as there's a possibility that you'll be mixing tapered threads and straight threads.

Even the more modern plumbing pipe materials still use iron pipe sizes for threaded fittings. This is for backwards compatibility with older systems like yours. The 1/2" size from your valve's marketing indicates a 1/2" iron pipe size, but that's the iron pipe's nominal size and therefore its *inner* diameter. The 2 cm dimension from the marketing is the 1/2" iron pipe's *outer* diameter, where looking up the outer diameter of 1/2" iron pipe and converting to metric confirms that (0.84")(2.54cm/in) = 2.1 cm. Note how this 2.1 cm does not match the installed valve's inlet diameter of about 1.75 cm.

Working in imperial units and from your image, the inlet pipe size is about (17.5mm)(1"/25.4mm) = 0.689". 3/8" steel pipe has a standard outer diameter of 0.675", so 3/8" FIP (female iron pipe) is your inlet thread.

Estimating from your image of the valve's outlet threads, I get about (14mm)(1"/25.4mm) = 0.551". 3/8" compression fittings call for 9/16" threads, where 9/16" = 0.563". The outlet thread is therefore 3/8" compression. I guess the dimensions are spec'ed under *SAE J514*, but it's behind a paywall. The dimensions are available at https://archive.org/details/fluidconductorsc0000unse/page/58/mode/2up from Figure 19B and column B of Table 7.

Comment: I kinda get it I think. I also did first find a valve that's 3/8 x 3/8, but got told current valve is 1/2. But to my original question though and for future reference, what should be the correct size of the coupler? Given the first 2 images.

Comment: @jqbotan, assuming that this valve is already in the mail, holds sentimental value, is unreturnable, etc., the adapter size would be 3/8" FIP × 1/2" FIP. You should buy pipe dope for the connections instead of PFTE tape, as there's a chance you'll be mixing straight and tapered threads.

Comment: @jqbotan, 1/2" is pretty standard nowadays for a valve like that. I checked it out of diligence, was initially surprised, and rechecked twice because it's counter-intuitive. Whoever told you 1/2", did he measure anything? All manufacturers size fittings in copper, PVC, etc. with standard iron pipe threads for backwards compatibility with older plumbing like yours. This makes fitting sizes quite easy in your case: Figure out the pipe _nominal_ size (the _inner_ diameter) and that's the size for an FIP (or FNPT) fitting.

Comment: They did not measure, it was from a local hardware store only. I showed them the same last picture with the old valve, and they insisted it's 1/2 and that it's the standard. But thank you very much for all the help! I think I got all the info I needed. And no I have not ordered anything yet since I wanted to get correct parts the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the markings on the connector: ( 1/2 304 )  That would have 1/2 NPT (pipe thread).

An angle valve having an inlet of  1/2 male NPT would thread right on there.